# Problem Using the System.Web.Caching.Cache Class in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, caching

So I am working on a project which uses ASP.NET.  I am trying to call Cache["key"] but the compiler complains about how System.Web.Caching.Cache is "nat valid at this point".

If I call Cache obj = new Cache(); the obj is always null.

I can access HttpContext.Current.Cache - but this doesnt let me specify an absolute expiration and sliding expiration in the Insert() method.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should be able to absolute or sliding expiration calling the insert on HttpRuntime.Cache. It has several overloads. Ex:

```
HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("EXAMPLE_KEY", 
                        exampleItem, 
                        Nothing,                           
                        DateTime.Now.AddHours(1),
                        System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
```

The exact same code should also work with HttpContext.Current.Cache.

Comment: Can't have an absolute expiration AND a sliding expiration?  It seems like it one or the other.

Comment: I am not sure how that would work, the two forms of expiration would surely contradict each other at some point. For this reason it is not allowed. One value should be supploed and the other should be System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration and System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration.

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863654/difference-between-httpruntime-cache-and-httpcontext-current-cache) there's no real benefit for using HttpContext.Current.Cache instead of HttpRuntime.Cache, so the code example you posted should suffice anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try PCache class under [PokeIn](http://pokein.codeplex.com) library. Even if you use FREE edition of that library, there is no limitation with this class. It has many more functionalities in comparison to ASP.NET Cache class and you dont have to deal with these problems. there is a simple sample project available on the web site.