# Difference between HttpRuntime.Cache and HttpContext.Current.Cache?

Tags: asp.net

What is the difference between `HttpRuntime.Cache` and `HttpContext.Current.Cache`?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I find following detail from http://theengineroom.provoke.co.nz/archive/2007/04/27/caching-using-httpruntime-cache.aspx

> For caching I looked into using
>   HttpContext.Current.Cache but after
>   reading other blogs I found that
>   caching using HttpContext uses
>   HttpRuntime.Cache to do the actual
>   caching. The advantage of using
>   HttpRuntime directly is that it is
>   always available, for example, in
>   Console applications and in Unit
>   tests.
>
> Using HttpRuntime.Cache is simple.
>   Objects can be stored in the cache and
>   are indexed by a string. Along with a
>   key and the object to cache the other
>   important parameter is the expiry
>   time. This parameter sets the time
>   before the object is dropped from the
>   cache.

**[Here is good link for you.](http://weblogs.asp.net/pjohnson/httpruntime-cache-vs-httpcontext-current-cache)**

[**Another good resource.**](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/UsingTheASPNETCacheOutsideOfASPNET.aspx)

Comment: The pjohnson page has moved to http://weblogs.asp.net/pjohnson/httpruntime-cache-vs-httpcontext-current-cache. The redirect doesn't work; took a while to find it with wayback machine.

Answer (score 19):

Caching using HttpContext uses HttpRuntime.Cache to do the actual caching. The advantage of using HttpRuntime directly is that it is always available in console applications and in unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

Using `HttpRuntime.Cache` is simple to use than `HttpContext.Current.Cache`.As already said that objects can be stored in the cache and are indexed by a string.Also in unit test and console `HttpRuntime` this available.

Here is an example to use `HttpRuntime.Cache`.

```
public static XmlDocument GetStuff(string sKey) 
{
XmlDocument xmlCodes;
xmlCodes = (XmlDocument) HttpRuntime.Cache.Get( sKey );
if (xmlCodes == null)
{
      xmlCodes = SqlHelper.ExecuteXml(new dn("Nodes", "Node"), "Get_Stuff_From_Database", sKey);
      HttpRuntime.Cache.Add(sKey, xmlCodes, null,
      DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1.0),
      System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
      System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
}
return xmlCodes;
}
```

#### What this example does actually:

---

The method `GetStuff` takes a string parameter which is used to retrieve a set of items from the database. The method first checks to see if an `XmlDocument` indexed by the parameter key is in the cache. If it is, it simply returns this object, if not it queries database. After it has retrieved the document from the database it then put it into cache. If this method is called again within the stipulated time, it will get the object rather than hitting the database.