# What's the difference between the HttpRuntime Cache and the HttpContext Cache?

Tags: asp.net, caching, httpcontext, httpruntime.cache

I know there is a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863654/difference-b-w-httpruntime-cache-vs-httpcontext-current-cache) but I was hoping to get a better explination. Why would I ever use HttpContext.Cache instead of HttpRuntime.Cache if the HttpContext really uses the HttpRuntime.Cache behind the scenes?

In the article [Simulate a Windows Service using ASP.NET to run scheduled jobs](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASPNETService.aspx) Omar uses the HttpContext to store his cache items, but when Jeff Atwood Implemented it [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/) he chose to use the HttpRuntime instead. Obviously in this particular situation it makes sense since since you don't have to do a web request to add the cache item back into the HttpContext.

However I'm looking for some good pointers as to when to use one versus the other.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It really is the same cache at the end, only `HttpContext.Current` can sometimes be null (when not in a web context, or in a web context but not yet constructed). You'd be safe to always use `HttpRuntime.Cache`.

Answer (score 2):

When you are in a regular web page, you can safely use `HttpContext.Cache` or just the `Cache` property of the page.

If you are doing something that's not in a page, you often need to use `HttpRuntime.Cache` to safely get access to it.

In some cases you can know if there is an http context or not, for example if you start a separate thread from a web page, that thread does not have http context. In other cases you may have an http context sometimes, like in the `Application_Start` method in `global.asax`, as the application may not always be started because there is a request.

Answer (score 2):

I find it misleading too although we all know it just returns `HttpRuntime.Cache` internally. Also the HttpRuntime is kind of a bad choice to expose the Cache I guess.

Everyone sais how `Session` is session-level cache and the Cache we're talking about is application-level. I would prefer to have `Application.Cache` as the cache we're using today and `HttpContext.Cache` to refer to what's known as `HttpContext.Items`.

As for answering your question, I think we should all stick to the HttpRuntime.Cache making our code clearer even if we do have various ways to access it. And when you seriously plan to use it you'd better wrap your own API and have that internally call the `HttpRuntime's` or any other cache implementation (EntLib, Velocity, etc...).